# Change Object with key into organized Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I'm trying to get stock data from an API and organize it in a DataFrame.
The RAW data is:

```
{"AAPL":[{"t":1590090900,"o":317.06,"h":317.32,"l":317,"c":317.07,"v":5654},{"t":1590090960,"o":317.07,"h":317.07,"l":316.77,"c":316.78,"v":6608},{"t":1590091020,"o":316.73,"h":316.77,"l":316.585,"c":316.71,"v":12578},{"t":1590091080,"o":316.855,"h":317.17,"l":316.855,"c":317.04,"v":8184},{"t":1590091140,"o":317,"h":317.45,"l":316.77,"c":317.06,"v":21572}]}
```

How would I be able to get a dataframe where the letters were the columns and the "t" the rows?

Comment: Welcome to SO! `pd.DataFrame(d["AAPL"]).set_index("t")`?

Comment: thanks! when I try I get "KeyError: 'AAPL' "

Comment: Did you use the exact structure you posted above? Works fine for me.

Comment: Yes! Finally got it, I was calling another stock before thanks so much!